# Aggregate rates from database

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection in MongoDB. Model is:

```
{
  currency: String,
  price: Number,
  time: Date
}
```

Documents are recorded to that collection any time the official rate for currency changes.

I am given a timestamp, and I need to fetch rates for all available currencies to that time. So first I need to filter all documents whose time $lte then required, then I need to fetch only those with max timestamps. For each currency.

Comment: Dear Konstantin, you know the rules. I didn't downvote with sincere hope you are going to update the question exposing your attempt to solve the problem. If the array in the second snippet is your collection of 6 documents you are not aggregating anything - you are filtering by time: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/index.html

Answer (score 1):

after seeing your requirement , I think you want max number of price and time , use [max operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/)

```
db.collection.aggregate(
   [
     {
       $group:
         {
           _id: "$currency",
           time: { $max: "$time"},
           price: { $max: "$price" }
         }
     }
   ]
)
```

Comment: Thank you for quick reply. Can you tell, what exactly does line `price: { $max: "$price" }` ? I need select document only by max time?

Answer (score 0):

You can use mongo aggregate function to do so. Please find the example below:

```
db.<collection_name>.aggregate([
        // First sort all the docs by time in descending
        {$sort: {time: -1}},
        // Take the first 3 of those
        {$limit: 3}
    ])
```

Hope this helps !!